# Is there a way to replace a whole pandas dataframe row using ffill, if one value of a specific column is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort a dataframe where some rows are all NaN. I want to fill these using ffill. I'm currently trying this although i feel like it's a mismatch of a few commands

```
df.loc[df['A'].isna(), :] = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

This gives an error:
 `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'`

but I want to filter the NaNs I fill using ffill if one of the columns is NaN. i.e.

```
     A    B      C     D   E
0   45    88    NaN   NaN  3
1   62    34    2     86   NaN
2   85    65    11    31   5
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
4   90    38    34    93   8
5    0    94    45    10   10
6   58    NaN   23    60   11
7   10    32     5    15   11
8   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

So I would only like to fill a row IFF the value of A is NaN, whilst leaving C,0 and D,0 as NaN. Giving the below dataframe

```
     A    B      C     D   E
0   45    88    NaN   NaN  3
1   62    34    2     86   NaN
2   85    65    11    31   5
3   85    65    11    31   5
4   90    38    34    93   8
5    0    94    45    10   10
6   58    NaN   23    60   11
7   10    32     5    15   11
8   10    32     5    15   11
```

So just to clarify, the ONLY rows that get replaced with ffill are 3,8 and the reason is because the value of column A in rows 3 and 8 are NaN
Thanks

---Update---
When I'm debugging and evaluate the expression : `df.loc[df['A'].isna(), :]`

I get

```
3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
8   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
```

So I assume whats happening here is, I then attempt ffill on this new dataframe only containing 3 and 8 and obviously i cant ffill NaNs with NaNs.

Comment: isn't that just `df.ffill()`?

Comment: That would fill all the nas though. I want to filter which columns I fill

Comment: Perhaps you can improve your example to more clearly illustrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, want to filter which rows I fill, via specific column values

Comment: Does your `df.loc[df['A'].isna(), :] = df.fillna(method='ffill')` work or not?  If not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Comment: Interesting. Maybe there's something else going on with my code

Comment: The error message `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'` suggests that your `df` is `None`. Check that you've loaded the data frame correctly or that you're using the right variable name.

Comment: Thanks Seb, the penultimate line of code prior to this was changing my df to None.

Answer (score 1):

Change values only to those row that start with nan

```
df.loc[df['A'].isna(), :] = df.ffill().loc[df['A'].isna(), :]

      A     B     C     D     E
0  45.0  88.0   NaN   NaN   3.0
1  62.0  34.0   2.0  86.0   NaN
2  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
3  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
4  90.0  38.0  34.0  93.0   8.0
5   0.0  94.0  45.0  10.0  10.0
6  58.0   NaN  23.0  60.0  11.0
7  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
8  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
```

Comment: still getting same error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ffill'`

Comment: Thanks, this works, my df was being made to None prior to these lines of code. apologies

Answer (score 1):

Try using a mask to identify the relevant rows where column `A` is null.  The take those same rows from the forward filled dataframe.

```
mask = df['A'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, :] = df.ffill().loc[mask, :]
>>> df
      A     B     C     D     E
0  45.0  88.0   NaN   NaN   3.0
1  62.0  34.0   2.0  86.0   NaN
2  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
3  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
4  90.0  38.0  34.0  93.0   8.0
5   0.0  94.0  45.0  10.0  10.0
6  58.0   NaN  23.0  60.0  11.0
7  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
8  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, my df was being made to None prior to these lines of code. apologies

Answer (score 0):

you just want to fill ([`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) ) **where**([`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)) `df['A']` is `nan` and the rest leave it as before (**df**):

```
df=df.ffill().where(df['A'].isna(),df)
print(df)
      A     B     C     D     E
0  45.0  88.0   NaN   NaN   3.0
1  62.0  34.0   2.0  86.0   NaN
2  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
3  85.0  65.0  11.0  31.0   5.0
4  90.0  38.0  34.0  93.0   8.0
5   0.0  94.0  45.0  10.0  10.0
6  58.0   NaN  23.0  60.0  11.0
7  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
8  10.0  32.0   5.0  15.0  11.0
```